# Rest API post restsharp JSON gives error

Tags: json, vb.net, rest

I have next piece of vb .net software to perform an Rest API call:
[enter image description here][1]

```
Dim jsonContentBody As String = stringWriter.ToString
Dim RestClient1 As New RestClient(myPars.url & "shipment/v2_1/label")
Dim request1 As New RestRequest

request1.Method = Method.POST
request1.AddHeader("apikey", myPars.apikey)
request1.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType)
request1.AddQueryParameter(name:="confirm", value:=confirm.ToString.ToLower)
request1.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request1.AddBody(jsonContentBody)
Dim response1 As IRestResponse(Of List(Of String)) = RestClient1.Execute(Of List(Of String))(request:=request1)
```

I get constantly next error with which google couldn't be of any assistent. 
Does anyone have a clue ?
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Execution of proxyPreFlow failed on line 8 with error: null","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailedLineNumber"}}}

Submitting the JSONBody into  SOAPUI or Postman gives no problem !?

Comment: Please, insert the code in the question since most of readers would not follow a link to view it. It is easier to give an answer having all the elements in sight.
Also, some edition could enhance your question. Separating and formatting the error to give it more visibility would make the problem clearer

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  One requirement here is that code needs to be inserted **as text** rather than as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3744182).  Beyond that, is there any chance you could [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]?  We're more likely to be able to help if you can help us reproduce the problem.  You might also read [ask] and take the [tour] for more tips on how to write a question that's likely to get answered.